# Looking for a better way to extract all parents from a tree object into a simple array

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

Here's a tree sample fetched via Typeorm:

```
interface Base {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  parent?: Base;
}

const sample: Base[] = [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "Son",
    parent: {
      id: "2",
      name: "Father",
      parent: {
        id: "3",
        name: "Grand Father",
      },
    },
  },
];
```

I want to generate a simple array of all parents from the tree object like this:

```
const output = [
   {
     id: "2",
     name: "Father",
   },
   {
     id: "3",
     name: "Grand Father",
   }
]
```

This is my recursive function:

```
function collect(obj: Base, output: Base[]) {
  if (obj.parent) {
    output = collect(obj.parent, output);
  }
  const { parent, ...rest } = obj;
  output.push(rest);
  return output;
}

let output = [];
output = collect(sample[0], output);

// Use pop to remove the last element which is the "Son" object.
output.pop();
```

Is there a better way to generate the array? I use the lodash library, would something like `_.flatMapDeep` work?

Comment: Don't know a better way to do this than what you have. You could try and update the query you are using to grab this information.

Answer (score 1):

There are some minor optimizations possible:

- Do not expose output array unnecessarily
- Just start collection one level deeper
- Recursion is unnecessary

```
function collect(input: Base) {
  const output = []; // Output contained in function
  let current = input.parent; // Skips self

  while (current != null) { // Loop instead of recursion
    const { parent, ...rest } = current;
    output.push(rest);
    current = current.parent;
  }

  return output;
};

console.log(collect(sample[0]));
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4oN4ChnLAAmAXMhmFKAOYDc+yIcAthGRVSHQwA5xQRwAfjLos9AL65cCAPYgK5FjwA2bNJggBtALrIAvMi0M8BAsTIAiAIyWANAwJNWVgMrz7j5HwHgyps3NSZEsAJk9ApxZ1SwAxODAAC2gIyJ9BMH8vQIsQgGZUyMZoqwBxKDgQImR4pJSHIokGsyaGVp16XBgAVxAEMGB5ZDkVNX6AClAebsyNLABKZAC5BTBkWRnptcNdegI1NYRuqF9twhAtgDp08D3kAHdE4DVkcaOTjOQAQkMQbtHFgECCtFNhvPwMnZkJcYQJFBIDMNjqc7gQNmArtMMIlxnCwPNUUiPuBEe9TtcIbc2tICAIwMcQOtNjNJJ0QbI1JcVLJqG8OWMwOMMMo1FoAAw6eYEoA)